# OpenMPI "nooversubscribe" does not work when using MPI_Comm_spawn

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have a simple `MPI_Comm_spawn`-based code that spawns 4 processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm intercomm;
    int final_nranks = 4, len;
    char name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &len);
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&intercomm);
    if(intercomm == MPI_COMM_NULL){
        MPI_Info info;
        MPI_Info_create(&info);
        MPI_Info_set(info, "hostfile", "hostfile");
        MPI_Info_set(info, "pernode", "true");
        MPI_Comm_spawn(argv[0], MPI_ARGV_NULL, final_nranks, info, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
        printf("PARENT %s\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("CHILD %s\n", name);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code with

```
$ mpirun  -np 2 --hostfile hostfile --map-by node ./a.out
```

I would expect something like:

```
PARENT node00
PARENT node01
CHILD node00
CHILD node01
CHILD node02
CHILD node03
```

I want that each process runs in a different node.
Since by default OpenMPI does not oversubscribe slots, I would expect that *child* processes were spawned in different nodes. But it is not the case. Instead, I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  PML add procs failed
  --> Returned "Not found" (-13) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[node00:50113] *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
[node00:50113] *** reported by process [3761700866,2]
[node00:50113] *** on a NULL communicator
[node00:50113] *** Unknown error
[node00:50113] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node00:50113] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[node00:200682] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-runtime.txt / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
[node00:200682] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[node00:200682] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal unknown handle
```

If I remove `MPI_Info_set(info, "pernode", "true");` from the code, the run does not crash but *child* processes are spawned in the same host:

```
PARENT node00
PARENT node01
CHILD node00
CHILD node00
CHILD node00
CHILD node00
```

OpenMPI version 4.1.2